# BigQuery ingestion throws "tableUnavailable" message: What causes this error specifically?

Tags: google-bigquery

Today, after many successful loads into a BigQuery table, received this error message:

```
tableUnavailable
Something went wrong with the table you queried. Contact the table owner for assistance
```

I do not see this error in the error table: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/troubleshooting-errors#errortable

What conditions could cause this error? Other load jobs, using the same code and in same dataset, do not display this error

Comment: Hi Michael! Can you share a project_id:job_id that hit this error? Feel free to email me at msheldon@google.com if you prefer to answer there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What causes a "tableUnavailable" message?

There are two cases that I can think of:

First, this error can be returned for queries over a (small) set of tables that BigQuery exposes access to, but are not directly managed by the BigQuery team itself. You can consider these equivalent to "internalError" from a troubleshooting perspective.

These data sources are typically accessible to GCP customers that have specific relationships with Google product teams exposing their data in BigQuery.

We expose these under a different error code since you will resolve the issue more quickly by contacting the group that granted you access to their data. Going through BigQuery customer support to get this resolved will work too, it'll just take a little longer.

Second, you encountered this through a load job so this is clearly not the case above! We are testing a new load implementation that is faster than the current implementation, and I suspect some errors are mapped slightly differently now.

In this case, I suspect you encountered a "backendError" and should try the operation again. If you can give us a project_id:job_id of a job that hit this problem, we can verify this and make sure the error mapping is more consistent.

Thank you!